# C++ fstream function that reads a line without extracting?

Tags: c++, fstream, extract, peek

In C++, is there a function in the fstream library (or any library) that allows me to read a line to a delimiter of '\n' without extracting?

I know the peek() function allows the program to 'peek' at the next character its reading in without extracting but I need a peek() like function that does that but for a whole line.

Comment: What is your use case for this? Sounds a bit like an XY problem.

Comment: its to read a text file and from it i want to use a peek() like function to determine if the next value that reading in is a sentential string or not. the method below worked perfectly for my problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `getline`, `tellg` and `seekg`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>


int main () {
    std::fstream fs(__FILE__);
    std::string line;

    // Get current position
    int len = fs.tellg();

    // Read line
    getline(fs, line);

    // Print first line in file
    std::cout << "First line: " << line << std::endl;

    // Return to position before "Read line".
    fs.seekg(len ,std::ios_base::beg);

    // Print whole file
    while (getline(fs ,line)) std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kleist this method works perfectly! So I assume there no peek() like function that read a line?

Comment: True, there is no such peek-function.

Comment: tellg returns std::streampos so should use that rather than int

Comment: Sadly that can't live in a `const` function, and it's probably not thread-safe.