# getline without advancing?

Tags: c++, position, getline

Is there a way to get the current line without advancing the position in the file?

I have an iterator for files that only calls `getline()` when `operator*()` is called to avoid needless copying of lines into strings. The iterator simply moves the position with `file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` every time `operator++` is called, however, this causes a line to be skipped when calling `operator*`, as that uses `getline()`. Therefore I would like to somehow get the current line but not advance the reading position. Is there a built in function that does this?

Comment: If it's a real file, and not a pipe or something, use `tellg()` to obtain the file position before `getline()`, then `seekg()` back to it.

Comment: Call `getline` in the `operator++` function instead? And of course on iterator construction. Then the `operator*` function just returns the current line.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but I don"t want to copy needlessly.

@SamVarshavchik I suspected `seekg` to have linear complexity, as "seek" kind of suggests that it does a search for the position. Is `seekg` cheap enough to do that every time `operator*` is called?

Comment: Copy *what*? I don't see any need for any copying.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude copying the line into a string: `getline(file, string)`

Comment: But you do that now too, in the dereference operator, don't you? Or do you mean that you don't have the line as a member variable? Perhaps it should be then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, but *only* there, not every time `operator++` is called.

Comment: If you use `ignore` to skip past the current line in the increment operator, you actually scan all characters in the file to be able to compare them to the newline. Instead of scanning and comparing you will scan and copy if you use `getline` instead. Complexity- and efficiency-wise there's really not much difference. *And* it will solve your problem. Go with simplicity and working code *first*, then if really needed (seldom and definitely not in your case) start pondering about optimizations.

Comment: ah, ok, I see. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [C++ fstream function that reads a line without extracting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10268872/3258851)